# Mocking is Not working in Spock Framework

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, spock

I am trying to write Spock Framework instead of Junit,

Test Class :

```
class StudentServiceSpec extends Specification{

@Shared def studentDao
@Shared def studentService

def setupSpec(){
    studentDao = Mock(StudentDao)
    studentService = new StudentService(studentDao)
}

def "Get Student Details Based on StudentId"(){

    setup:
    1*studentDao.getStudent(67) >> new Student()

    when:
    Response response = studentService.getStudent("67")
    println "** Response "+response
    println "** Response "+response.getEntity()

    then:
    response != null
    }
}
```

When I Run the above code using maven clean install command, I am getting the following error.

Error :

```
    1*studentDao.getStudent(67) >>> new Student()   (0 invocations)
```

If I Use `0*studentDao.getStudent(67) >>> new Student()`
I am Getting `response.getEntity()` is `null`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found my mistake...

I replaced the following code

```
@Shared def studentDao
@Shared def studentService

def setupSpec(){
studentDao = Mock(StudentDao)
studentService = new StudentService(studentDao)
}
```

with these two lines

```
 StudentDao studentDao = Mock()
 StudentService studentService = new StudentService(studentDao)
```

If we use `@Shared` its mocking the `class` but not mocking the `method call`

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons that why this is not working.

One reason is that there might be inconsistencies with the data type of parameter you are using in the actual code and in the test. Say for example below

```
studentDao.getStudent(67)
```

check if your Dao method getStudent accepts long data type or int data type. That 67 might be treated as int in your spock test while in your actual code, the method getStudent only accepts long data type. Thus, failing to mock the call of studentDao.getStudent(67) to return new Student().

Other might be, the id was changed before the actual invocation of dao method getStudent

so.

1. check the data type of the parameter your studentDao.getStudent(_) if its long, try 67L in your test
2. check if there are other code modifying the id before invocation of your dao method

As for the result with null

```
0*studentDao.getStudent(67) >>> new Student() I am Getting response.getEntity() is null
```

The null is expected since there is no mocking of your dao method to return Student object.